# How can I switch to the classic menu in Chrome beta?

Tags: google-chrome-beta

After updating to 26.0.1410.19 beta-m, my Chrome menu has a different look. Is it possible to switch back to classic menu view whilst staying on the beta channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right-click your Google Chrome shortcut (if it's in the taskbar, right-click the icon, then right-click "Google Chrome" in the popup menu).
2. Select "Properties."
3. Click the "Shortcut" tab if it's not already highlighted.
4. In the "Target" field, add **-–disable-new-menu-style** to the end of whatever's already there (with two hyphens before "disable"):
5. Click Apply, then OK.

*Source: [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5994121/how-to-disable-chromes-annoying-new-right+click-menu-style)*